# Decodificar Lista en FLutter

Tags: lista, flutter

Hola estoy usando provider y quiero decodificar lo siguiente he utilizado https://quicktype.io/ para generar el modelo

```
    [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "uid": "uWb0PKBbhBZVirLh0bllk2ncDRp1",
        "contrato": "5600009418",
        "nombres": "VICTOR BOLIVAR MURILLO ROBLES",
        "email": "alejoquimi@gmail.com",
        "cedula": "0900000",
        "direccion": "PLAYAS BARRIO EL PARAISO",
        "direccion1": "Santa Elena",
        "telefono": "0986287796",
        "estado": "Activo",
        "idcompany": "0190483843001",
        "idc": "5600012646",
        "ip": "10.59.20.63",
        "plan": "Plan Intro + Defence"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "uid": "uWb0PKBbhBZVirLh0bllk2ncDRp1",
        "contrato": "2400002545",
        "nombres": "VICTOR BOLIVAR MURILLO ROBLES",
        "email": "aaa",
        "cedula": "aaa",
        "direccion": "aa",
        "direccion1": "aaa",
        "telefono": "aaa",
        "estado": "aaa",
        "idcompany": "aaa",
        "idc": "aaa",
        "ip": "aaa",
        "plan": "aaa"
    }
]
```

en mi clase de servicios donde llamo al api tengo el siguiente codigo

```
    var uri = Uri.https(_baseUrl, _endpoint, params);
      final response = await _httpClient.get(uri);
      return List<Contratomodel>.from(json
          .decode(response.body)
          .map((c) => Contratomodel.fromJson(c))
          .toList());
```

pero haciendo un try me obtiene el siguiente error

_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of String

El modelo que me da quicktype es

```
class Contratomodel {
  Contratomodel({
    this.id,
    this.uid,
    this.contrato,
    this.nombres,
    this.email,
    this.cedula,
    this.direccion,
    this.direccion1,
    this.telefono,
    this.estado,
    this.idcompany,
    this.idc,
    this.ip,
    this.plan,
  });

  String? id;
  String? uid;
  String? contrato;
  String? nombres;
  String? email;
  String? cedula;
  String? direccion;
  String? direccion1;
  String? telefono;
  String? estado;
  String? idcompany;
  String? idc;
  String? ip;
  String? plan;

  factory Contratomodel.fromJson(String str) =>
      Contratomodel.fromMap(json.decode(str));

  String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());



factory Contratomodel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Contratomodel(
    id: json["id"],
    uid: json["uid"],
    contrato: json["contrato"],
    nombres: json["nombres"],
    email: json["email"],
    cedula: json["cedula"],
    direccion: json["direccion"],
    direccion1: json["direccion1"],
    telefono: json["telefono"],
    estado: json["estado"],
    idcompany: json["idcompany"],
    idc: json["idc"],
    ip: json["ip"],
    plan: json["plan"],
  );
Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
    "id": id,
    "uid": uid,
    "contrato": contrato,
    "nombres": nombres,
    "email": email,
    "cedula": cedula,
    "direccion": direccion,
    "direccion1": direccion1,
    "telefono": telefono,
    "estado": estado,
    "idcompany": idcompany,
    "idc": idc,
    "ip": ip,
    "plan": plan,
  };
```

}

la respuesta que me trae en el response decodificado es

```
I/flutter (14034): [{id: 1, uid: uWb0PKBbhBZVirLh0bllk2ncDRp1, contrato: 5600009418, nombres: VICTOR BOLIVAR MURILLO ROBLES, email: alejoquimi@gmail.com, cedula: 0900778523, direccion: PLAYAS BARRIO EL PARAISO, direccion1: Santa Elena, telefono: 0986287796, estado: Activo, idcompany: 190483843001, idc: 5600012646, ip: 10.59.20.63, plan: Plan Intro + Defence}, {id: 2, uid: uWb0PKBbhBZVirLh0bllk2ncDRp1, contrato: 2400002545, nombres: VICTOR BOLIVAR MURILLO ROBLES, email: aaa, cedula: aaa, direccion: aa, direccion1: aaa, telefono: aaa, estado: aaa, idcompany: aaa, idc: aaa, ip: aaa, plan: aaa}]
```

Trae los datos de la base sin problemas, al hacerle un print son los datos que espero, pero sé que mi problema es en la conversion o asignacion de la lista

Comment: podrías agrega la clase Contratomodel que te generó?

Comment: también trata de agregar el endpoint o una respuesta real de lo que obtienes al llamar a esa url

Comment: Has un print a response.body para ver que te devuelve

Comment: @diegoveloper ahi esta mas detallado, recibo los datos de la consulta sin problema pero sé que mi problema es al tema de la decodificación porque lo que me devuelve es un list,, pero no se como hacerlo

Comment: @JonathanPerez lo agregué en este momento si me trae datos, pensé que el problema era porque habia algunos campos nulos y por eso puse como opcionales a todos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si el modelo lo tienes estructurado de la manera correcta, y si lo que te devuelve la api es exactamente lo que muestras, no tendrás problema en esa parte, te sugiero que separes el código para que puedas manejarte mejor, te voy a dar un ejemplo de como yo decodifico lo que me devuelve la api, pero con tu mismo código, solo modificado un poco, para que te sirva de guía:

```
    Future<List<Contratomodel>?> getData() async {
    List<Contratomodel>? dataList;
    try {
      var uri = Uri.https(_baseUrl, _endpoint, params);
      final response = await _httpClient.get(uri);

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        final decodeResponse = json.decode(response.body);

        if (decodeResponse != null && decodeResponse.isNotEmpty) {
          dataList = [];
          for (var contrato in decodeResponse) {
            final newData = Contratomodel.fromJson(contrato);
            dataList.add(newData);
          }

          return dataList;
        }
      }
    } on HttpException catch (e) {
      debugPrint(e.message);
    }
    return dataList;
  }
```